# 'import-resolver-typescript/lib' not found error in jsconfig.json

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, frontend, next.js

### Problem:

Error `File '/Users/nish7/Documents/Code/WebDev/HOS/frontend/node_modules/eslint-import-resolver-typescript/lib' not found. The file is in the program because: Root file specified for compilation`

### Steps to reproduction:

- create-next-app
- npx jsconfig.json -t nextjs

jsconfig.json

```
    "compilerOptions": {
        "checkJs": false,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "target": "es2020",
        "module": "es2015",
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "@/components/*": ["components/*"],
            "@/styles/*": ["styles/*"],
            "@/pages/*": ["pages/*"],
            "@/utils/*": ["utils/*"],
            "@/theme/*": ["theme/*"]
        }
    },
    "exclude": [
        "dist",
        "node_modules",
        "build",
        ".vscode",
        ".next",
        "coverage",
        ".npm",
        ".yarn"
    ],
    "typeAcquisition": {
        "enable": true,
        "include": ["react", "react-dom"]
    }
}
```

#### eslint.rc

```
{
  "extends": ["next", "next/core-web-vitals"]
}
```

#### Specs

- vscode: Version 1.57.1
- node: 14.17.1 (LTS)
- nextjs: 11.0.1

#### note: I added eslint-import-resolver-typescript module, but still dint work.

#### Screenshot:

[image: SS]

Comment: Did you later fix this? I'm having the same issue too

Comment: I tried to fix it was unable to find a concrete solution however application did run without errors, so I ignored it. if it's really bugging you, uninstalling javascript/typescript IntelliSense extension may stop but you won't get the IntelliSense features as well.

Comment: Also having this exact same problem. Am struggling to even find a way to just turn off the error message.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are using vscode, try to disable `TypeScript › Validate` in settings. This solved it for me!

**Edit:**

Found a more sensible approach than totally disabling validation; setting the TypeScript SDK in the Vscode setting

`"typescript.tsdk": "./node_modules/typescript/lib"`

Comment: I've been wrestling with this issue for weeks and no solution I tried worked until this one. Thanks....

Comment: Where should we add that key?

Comment: in settings.json. Press f1 in vscode and type settings.json and add that line there. This just fixed my problem, thank you Solly.

Answer (score 1):

Just restart your all vscode windows, that worked in my case.

Comment: exactly! close visual studio code and reopen!